# Possible to make MSVC explain the reasons why it is unable to return a small struct in a register?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, calling-convention

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7572ztz4.aspx):

> To be returned by value in RAX, user-defined types must have a length of 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits; no user-defined constructor, destructor, or copy assignment operator; no private or protected non-static data members; no non-static data members of reference type; no base classes; no virtual functions; and no data members that do not also meet these requirements.

Obviously I can go through my code and verify all these attributes myself.  But it would be nice to get a message from the compiler explaining why it is unable to return a struct in a register from a given function.  Is there any option I can turn on to get such messages?

Comment: A commercial product isn't especially designed to emit "you suck" messages.  It just does what you ask it to do.

Comment: Just reinterpret the raw bits to a C type as you see fit yourself. :P

Make a suggestion to the MSVC team. They can only improve their product with feedback.

Comment: if you're using c++11 you can examine the type using the template classes in the <type_traits> header

Comment: @HansPassant: Most of the MSVC warnings listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23k5d385.aspx) sure sound like "you suck" messages to me.  Plus there's [/Qvec-report](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj614596.aspx), which reports detailed reasons if it is unable to optimize - just like my question.